# How to determine optimal lighting around monitors?

Tags: display

I use multiple monitors and want to adjust/situate my lamps optimally to protect eyesight and health, against fatigue, glare, etc... How can I determine this?

I've read http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/is-sitting-too-close-to-screen-making-you-blind/.

Comment: From the knowledge you've learned via that link, your best bet is going to be trial and error. Place your monitors/lamps so they don't glare, etc. Things that article mentions. Also something I've found that helps is f.lux. It yellows your screen which is easier on the eyes, especially in darker lighting.

Comment: This is highly subjective and will only attract opinions.  It's also an ergonomics problem and not an actual problem with computer software or hardware. It is a problem entirely to do with wetware, not hardware or software, and as such would also be off topic for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jAce mentioned in a comment, you'll find the optimal lightning by trial and error; just see what works for you best.

From my experience, I feel comfortable with the natural skylight and warm light bulbs. When there's no light, I have headaches after staying in front of the monitor, for too long (and it's not a monitor problem*).

For the position of the light source, I think it's important not to see it, or have it filtered through an translucent material.

For the glare part, if you have a glossy screen, I think you should put the monitor so it doesn't reflect any source lights, this should be enough. Side note: Many people hate glossy screens, I personally like them, everything looks a little more crisp and colorful. I think it's a matter of preference.

Also, set the brightness of the monitors to match the one of the light sources. The brighter the room you're staying, the brighter you can set the monitors.

One thing I wouldn't do is to have the monitor equipped with a protective film. It just makes everything ugly. If the monitor requires a protective film just to look at him, it's just a bad monitor*.

* Now, on the monitors side. Many say every monitor is the same (as eye fatigue goes), and, perhaps it counts just the refresh rate. The latter is pretty valid, but that's not all. I am pretty sensitive to bad displays, and I can tell you not all 60Hz (vertical refresh rate) displays are the same. I think the way pixels are refreshed (vertically and horizontally) might have something to do with the fatigue, I'm not sure, but there is a difference. After 30 minutes on a bad monitor, I already have a little headache. Brightness might be another issue, but it shouldn't (if you're not exaggerating with the levels); I've seen monitors with bright light which were perfectly fine, and monitors where I had to set the brightness so low to have no headache that I had to concentrate to see anything. Anyway, the idea is that not only the surrounding lighting counts for your overall health, but also the monitors themselves.

One more thing, about the light. Cold light affects you more than warm light. We have more green and red receptors than blue receptors, at the level of the retina, thus for every blue point we perceive, the brain has to work more than for any red or green points. So, another thing you could do is have warm light bulbs (like I mentioned earlier), and also set the monitor colors to a warm tone.

Answer (score 0):

We use 3 ways here to reduce harsh light beaming in on the peripheral.

1) Put the light completly outside of the view, this often takes a longer arm desklight, or using normal room or office lighting. Without any harsh tight beams of light, or filaments or led items shooting harsh light quantity in the peripheral.

2) Shade the light, so it lights around the desk, the keyboard and papers and all, but the filament or highest concentration of the light is blocked from slamming the backs of your retina.  I like to use reflective mylar to bounce the light to other locations, so I do not lose the light.

3) Light just the keyboard with strip light, or lighted keyboards. This method is not very useful for viewing papers and all, but works to light needed things without harsh point light from being in the peripheral vision.  of course when cave lighting, it helps to turn down the actual backlight of the monitor, not all monitors will turn down the backlight, instead they crunch up the total dynamic colors by using the light valves instead.

Other things I have not done, because of original purchase descisions: Matte bezels, non-glare screens.
 Due to selected position of the desks and all, minimal reflections, and no windows behind.  All of it is a balance, no extremes.  Exercise those lens muscles, keep sharp beams from striking dependant on how far the eye iris is open.  Previous TV watching advice suggested having normal lighting around the tv as opposed to it being a harsh light in a dark location. Again it is a balance.